# Compute $(I+A)^{-1}$ from $(I+\alpha A)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Assuming $A$ is symmetric and postive semifdefinate. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are all less than 1, then we can use $(I+A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0} (-1)^nA^n$ to approximate $(I+A)^{-1}$.

My question is that what if some eigenvalues of $A$ is larger than 1. How can we use the approximation $(I+A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0} (-1)^nA^n$. What I am thinking is let $\alpha = \frac{1}{\lambda_{max} +c}$, where $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and $c>0$. Then the eigenvalues of $\alpha A$ are all smaller than 1. Then we can approximate $(I+\alpha A)^{-1}$. Can we use $(I+\alpha A)^{-1}$ to compute $(I+A)^{-1}$?